# When do I become an employee: upon signing a job offer or the start date?

Tags: united-states, employer-relations

I'm signing a lease agreement and I'm not sure which company to name as my current employer.

The situation is that I have signed a job offer from a company but the start date is still about a week away. Is the company officially/legally/in-a-widely-accepted-definition my employer at this stage, or not?

Comment: Both. Your agreement indicates at which date you start.

Comment: Have you asked the company you're signing the lease agreement with which employer they would prefer?  Depending on why they're asking, my guess is that they'd prefer the job you're starting in a week even if you haven't technically started yet.

Comment: I just did the same thing.  Apply for a rental place while signing a new contract.  I simply put the start date on the "current" employer under length of employment (indicating it is very soon, pretty much before they process the forms, check my credits and call my references).  It worked out fine... when they finally got around to calling my "current" employer to verify my employment, I have already been there for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caveat: this is not legal advice, if this is important consult a lawyer.

Typically its your start date. Your employment begins with the first paid hour and ends with the last paid hour

Answer (score 3):

In the context of the lease, ask the person who you are signing it for. They would probably chuckle if you put someone you have 5 days left for and wouldn't mind the new job being there.

Answer (score 0):

As at this point in time, your employer is the current employer.
When your lease starts, you may be expected to update your employment status, however, up until then, your employer is the current one.
If the information is that important to them, then they could as well as if you are on a notice to leave period.

Comment: Please re-read your last sentence. It is confusing me.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter.  The people asking you to sign the lease agreement just want to see that you have a job.  So put in your new job.

Comment: And if they call that company for something? It won't know who you are.